# Dialog selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, ios7

Since some of our users have upgraded to **iOS7** we are finding that some pages within out **phonegap (cordova)** application seem to be failing. The scenario is this:

A user wants to book a job, therefore they click to book it, a dialogue appears and they select the number of hours to book it for, they then click book.   The Application talks to our server with AJAX which sends back a result. If there was an error (e.g. they cannot book the person, then the application shows another dialogue box.  However when we try to run JavaScript on this dialogue as soon as it tries to access a div through `$('#Warnings')` the application just stops functioning.

Can any one suggest why this is happening and what is going on.  (It works on iOS6, I have logging to know that it has go to just before appending a `li` to `ul`, I have tried changing the event we move it to, seeing if the div exists (which caused the app to crash), moving the JavaScript to the bottom of the page. I have just run out of ideas!

We are running **JQuery-Mobile 1.3.2**, **JQuery 1.9**. Append seems to work on all the other pages, in the same fashion as we have here.

```
if (Ps.Logic.Type.hasValue(logicResult.Warnings)) {

    for (var f in logicResult.Warnings) {
        //add to warnings list
        Ps.File.Log("Diary_Logic_Error_Dialogue: Processing Warnings : (" + f + ") " + logicResult.Warnings[f], function () {
            //code
        });
        $('#WarningsList').append("<li>" + logicResult.Warnings[f] + "</li>");

        Ps.File.Log("Diary_Logic_Error_Dialogue: Processing Warnings : Added (" + f + ")", function () {
            //code 
        });
    }

    Ps.File.Log("Diary_Logic_Error_Dialogue: Processing Warnings : Done", function () {
        //code
    });

} else {
    Ps.File.Log("Diary_Logic_Error_Dialogue: Processing Warnings - No Value (Skipping)", function () {
        //code
    });
}
```

**Edit:**

Essentially what happens is the user places a job into a time slot they then get the following dialogue:

[image: The user confirms their selection]

When the user clicks "Allocate Booking" the client talks to the server which checks everything this end if there is a problem then it should show the following dialogue:

[image]

On ios6, this works perfectly, the error is shown, the user can continue or cancel.  However since updating to ios7 when we try to show this dialogue (the one in image 2) then it seems to stop processing the page as soon as we try to do something that edits / appends items to the DOM.

Comment: When do you select the dialog? btw, is it a dialog or a popup (_just for clarification_). if it's a dialog, try `$(document).on('pageshow', '#warning', function () {};`.

Comment: Its a dialogue, the warning is a ul which then has items added to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that placing an event listener on the page we were going to doesn't actually work - its as if the DOM is not there when then event gets called.  e.g.

**Index.html**

```
 $.mobile.changePage("Page.html")
```

**Page.html**

```
$('#diary_Logic_error_dialog_page').on("pageshow", function () {
    $('#ProceedButton').bind("click", Test);
});
```

However we cant seem to do it like this.  It seems as if, at least in ios7, we have to do something more like:

**Index.html**

(this line for me is actually in another javascript file which is referenced by the index.html page.)

```
$(document).delegate('#page', "pageshow", function (event) { PageShowExample() });
```

...

```
$.mobile.changePage("Page.html")
```

**Page.html**

```
function PageShowExample() { ... }
```

By doing this it seems as if the DOM is there when the page show is called, therefore it does not die as soon as we try and manipulate the DOM.